# Flex Lexer - iostream.h and others

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am trying to use Flex to generate a scanner. The version is 2.5.4. from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm website.

I am using [the example from the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html).

My enviroment is Windows 7 running VS2010.

So I execute the command `flex -c++ scanner.l` to generate `lex.yy.cc`.

I create a simple console app. and include the dir "C:\GnuWin32\include", containing `flexlexer.h` and `unistd.h`.

I also add the file `lex.yy.cc` to VS2010 and compile and get the error:

> c:\gnuwin32\include\flexlexer.h(47): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'iostream.h': No such file or directory

So I change `iostream.h` for `iostream`. But now I am getting:

> c:\gnuwin32\include\flexlexer.h(72): error C2061: syntax error :
>   identifier 'ostream'

The problem is that is defined in namespace std. I imagined I could compile flex to C++ without this kind of problem.

Am I doing something wrong? using wrong versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download and use Win flex-bison and everything is ok now.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/